# Error: The MDX function CURRENTMEMBER failed because the coordinate for the attribute contains a set

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas, mdx

How to handle this error:

> The MDX function CURRENTMEMBER failed because the coordinate for the  attribute contains a set.

when executing MDX query:

```
SELECT (
 { [Measures].[Amount]} 
 )ON COLUMNS,
 (
[OrganizationUnits].[Description].[Description].MEMBERS,
[OrganizationUnits].[IsCURRENT].[IsCURRENT]
) ON ROWS
FROM

(SELECT  [OrganizationUnits].[Description] ON 0
FROM
[CubeName]
WHERE( 

{[OrganizationUnits].[Description].&[Unit1],[OrganizationUnits].[Description].&[Unit2]}
)
)
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have a calculated member in your cube that uses the `.CurrentMember`, probably something like `[OrganizationUnits].[Description].CurrentMember`. This causes an error with sets having more than one member in the where condition, like you have it with

```
WHERE( 

{[OrganizationUnits].[Description].&[Unit1],[OrganizationUnits].[Description].&[Unit2]}
)
```

The following article - as well as the one it references at the top - contain some suggestions how to work around this type of problem: https://web.archive.org/web/20170514194410/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2007/01/13/multiselect-friendly-mdx-for-calculations-looking-at-current-coordinate.aspx